# range of non-ASCII

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

please give me a range of utf-8
example:

```
>>> s
'\xe9\x98\xbf\xe5\xaf\x8c\xe6\xb1\x97Afghanistan'
>>>re.findall('[\x00-\xff]+',s)
['\xe9\x98\xbf\xe5\xaf\x8c\xe6\xb1\x97Afghanistan']
```

I need out put:

```
'\xe9\x98\xbf\xe5\xaf\x8c\xe6\xb1\x97'
```

Comment: `'[\x00-\xff]'` matches *all bytes in a bytestring*. Did you mean you wanted the **non-ASCII bytes**?

Comment: Sounds as if you want the inverse of [Replace non-ASCII characters with a single space](//stackoverflow.com/q/20078816)

Comment: And to be clear: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. Any data that is valid ASCII is also valid UTF-8.

Comment: Last but not least: What are you trying to do? Do you really need the high bytes only? Then select `[\x80-\xff]+`.

Comment: thanks '[\x80-\xff]+' is work

Comment: It Would be useful to modify the title of the question in a more precise form. I would use 'Regular Expression range to select non-Ascii', or something similar

Comment: Also, To put as code the string you need as output '\xe9\x98\xbf\xe5\xaf\x8c\xe6\xb1\x97' so that is easier to read the post. (sorry i can't modify it myself, i don't have the rights yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `'[\x00-\xff]'` you are selecting all possible chars.

What you need in your case is a smaller range. For non-ASCII, please try:

**Input:**

```
re.findall('[^\x00-\x7f]', s)
```

**Output:**

```
['\xe9', '\x98', '\xbf', '\xe5', '\xaf', '\x8c', '\xe6', '\xb1', '\x97']
```

If you need the output to be not a list, but a single string (as you specified in the last row of your question, just do this way

**Input:**

```
re.findall('[^\x00-\x7f]+', s)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
'\xe9\x98\xbf\xe5\xaf\x8c\xe6\xb1\x97'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex pattern to find out only non ascii.

```
re.findall(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',s)
```